# Trying to prove for all integers: $n \ge 1 \implies \frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \ge \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

Tags: inequality, logic

Been racking my brain on this one..

I've tried some things but not sure if it flows logically:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}: n \ge 1$

$n+2 \ge 1$

$2n+2 \ge n+1$

$\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \ge \frac{n+1}{2n+1}$

Does this make sense? I'm not sure where to go..

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the answers. I'm trying to learn how to flow from starting with $n \ge 1$ and then manipulating the inequality in a series of logical steps to arrive at what's to the right of the implication, e.g., $n \ge 1$, $n+1 \ge 2$,...,$\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \ge \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$.

Comment: Try to square both sides and cancel out non important terms.

Comment: What's the purpose of $x \in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: good question..

Answer (score 4):

Using $2 a * b \le a^2 + b^2 $ to prove
$$\frac{2n + 1}{2}  = \frac{ n + (n+1)}{2} $$
$$\ge \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n + 1} $$

Divide both sides by $n+1$

$$\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \ge \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since both sides are non-negative, we can square them without introducing new solutions. We have:
$$\left(1 - \frac1{2n + 2}\right)^2 \geq \frac{n}{n+1},$$
which is equivalent to
$$1 - \frac1{n+1} + \frac1{(2n + 2)^2} \geq \frac{n}{n+1}$$
We conclude
$$\frac1{(2n + 2)^2} \geq 0$$

The last inequality is true for $n \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \ge \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

is equivalent to

$(2n+1)^2  (n+1) \ge (2n+2)^2  n$

Check this by calculating all terms.